# Help with installing sudo apts

Tags: installation, apt, sudo, clamav

Any time I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to open command line and I type a command such as:

```
sudo apt-get install clamav clamtk
```

I click on it and it doesn't do anything.  Am I not supposed to click on the icon that comes up and reboot or am I missing a step?

Any help will do,

Thanks

Comment: Please mark a question as answered if you feel one has been provided.

Comment: Have you solved your question?

Answer (score 3):

use `gksudo` instead of sudo, i.e.,

```
 gksudo apt-get install clamav clamtk
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use terminal for this. You can start it by pressing Ctrl-Alt-t

PS. In 11.10 you'd probably need to check if the shortcut is assigned, but for 11.10 it's not the biggest issue.